# Gradle war plugin not including output from custom plugin

Tags: gradle

I have created simple custom gradle plugin that generates properties file and I need that properties file included in the root of the classpath. All works fine with "java" plugin - properties file is included in the root of the jar file.
I would expect the war file to include the properties file to the WEB-INF\classes but that is not happening...

I get the property file created in build/createVersion (i.e the task is executed) but it is not included in resources. When I change the build.gradle to include the task output directory then properties file is packaged just fine...

Here is simplified code for the plugin

```
class VersionGeneratorPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        // apply java plugin
        project.configure(project) {
            apply plugin: 'java'
        }
        // Add the 'versioning' extension object
        project.extensions.create("versioning", VersionExtension)
        // add task to create version.properties file
        project.task('createVersion') {
            // inputs and outputs of the task - using closures to have extension data available
            // .. inputs definition ...
            outputs.dir(project.file({ "${project.buildDir}/createProperties" }))

            doLast {
                // create property file
            }

            doFirst {
                // load defaults or use data from extension
            }
        }
        // add the properties file to the jar/war file
        project.sourceSets.main.resources {
            srcDirs project.files(project.createVersion.outputs)
        }
        // create dependency from classes to this task
        project.processResources.dependsOn(project.createVersion)
    }
}

class VersionExtension {
    // .. extension data I want passed in from the build ..
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong? Why is the task output not being included to the war file but it is included in the jar files? AFAIK I did all I should do

- define output of the task
- added the output to the resources
- made task execute before processResources task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK turned out the question was incorrect. I was able to resolve the issue by changing the resource declaration in the build script - i.e. the plugin task was OK but build script did this

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = [
                'resource_folder',
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This overwrites the configuration made by plugin. Correct form is following (added the +)

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs += [
                'resource_folder',
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Most likely there is still something wrong with my plugin because gradle documentation uses "=" instead of "+=" and I'd say my plugin is the only one broken by this...